# Finding the RMS value

Tags: rms

[image]

Here, I can't understand the third step. Why they ignored other three terms \$(40000\sin\omega t\sin 3\omega t, 10000\sin 3\omega t\sin 5\omega t, 20000\sin 5\omega t\sin\omega t)?\$ Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace \$\sin(A)\sin(B)\$ with \$\frac{1}{2}(\cos(A-B)-\cos(A+B))\$. ([Reference](http://www.macs.hw.ac.uk/%7Ebernd/F12MR2/mformula.pdf))
Perform the integration after doing the above substitution. It will be zero since area under the curve of \$\cos(\cdot)\$ is zero over the range of integration performed.